# How to get the context lo launch a intent method from other class

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to call a mehod from another activity. This method have a Intent inside and I'm sure that the problem is with the context in the intent. I read some similars answer but I can't do it... I get a nullpointerException

ActivityA

This is the method with the intent...

```
public void startGreetingRecorder() {
        Intent recordIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        .
        .
        startActivityForResult(recordIntent,);

    }
```

ActivityB

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.menu_save) {

            ActivityA.startGreetingRecorder();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is that I'm trying to do but don't work.

ActivityA

This is the method with the intent...

```
public void startGreetingRecorder(Context context) {
        Intent recordIntent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
        .
        .
        startActivityForResult(recordIntent,);

    }
```

ActivityB

protected Context context;

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.menu_save) {

            ActivityA.startGreetingRecorder(context);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: are both of the ways not working? Also you can't do `ActivityA.startGreetingRecorder(context);` unless method `startGreetingRecorder` is static.

Comment: The method in ActivityA is working. The problem is if I do static the method I get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are statically calling the method, so you need to mark the method as static as well as sending a context.

Activity A: (the receiver)

```
public static void startGreetingRecorder(final Activity a) {
  Intent recordIntent = new Intent(a, NewActivity.class);
        .
        .
  a.startActivityForResult(recordIntent,<SomeInteger>);

}
```

Activity B: (the caller)

[Edit] - Added the integer argument. This is used for handling the result.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.menu_save) {

        ActivityA.startGreetingRecorder(this);

    }
    return true;
}
```

If you don't actually need to handle the result, you can use `context.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: I have this error in c.startActivityForResult: "Cannot resolv method 'startActivityForResult'"

Comment: @D.O. I added the required parameter, you'll need to set a constant to use.

Comment: Yep, I had the constant, but I continue with the same problem c.startActivityForResult: "Cannot resolv method 'startActivityForResult'" I try to do this, but not work....        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(recordIntent, MY_CONSTANT);

Comment: I find the solution, Only one change in your code and is working. public static void startGreetingRecorder(Activity c). If you can edit....

Comment: You are welcome. Someone vote wrong my question... I thought that this is a place where beginners can do a simple questions, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call and activity method from other Activity in that way, you can use EventBus to achieve communication between activities.

Try with [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)